# Firefox not working with selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox

I'm using firefox 41.0b1 and selenium standalone 2.53.1 .issue is firefox run in sometimes and not always.error is **Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7056 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:** also I'm using testNG.hoping for a good solution

Comment: you need to change your firefox version.

Comment: can you specify any ff version

Comment: try `FF45` .. it should work.

Answer (score 0):

this combination of firefox and selenium won`t work.
you could try to upgrade your firefox to version 47.0.1 which works with selenium 2.53.1

Answer (score 0):

Use `gecokDriver` instead of `firefoxDriver` it will work smoothly with any version of firefox.

Code will look like below, make sure to set appropriate path where your gecodriver.exe is located:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        cap.setCapability("marionette", true);
        WebDriver driver = new MarionetteDriver(cap);
        driver.get("http://www.seleniumhq.org");
        driver.quit();
```